# DisconnectedContext/ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, events, logging

I have RichTextBox which I do heavy message logging from multi threads.
After some time I first received the "DisconnectedContext was detected" message and I removed the breaking on exception from the Debug->Exceptions... window. But then I received "ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected". I removed this too and the UI came back to life.
After some time it freezed again.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a component that supports coloring, changing fonts to give a visual feedback in .NET like RichTextBox but without this error?

> **ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected**
>   **Message:** The CLR has been unable to
>   transition from COM context 0x6eb0760
>   to COM context 0x6eb08d0 for 60
>   seconds. The thread that owns the
>   destination context/apartment is most
>   likely either doing a non pumping wait
>   or processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are updating the RichTextBox from multiple threads? If so you'd better stop that and use the UI thread to update the RTB. To do that: call `theForm.BeginInvoke( delegate to a method that updates the RTB)`

This should allow all the concurrent threads to continue ASAP without waiting for response.

Comment: You can only update a UI element from the UI thread, so, obviously, this is not the issue. I have the same problem and I update the textbox I use periodically from the UI thread, by reading some variables set by threads. This message keeps appearing.